# What is the name of this type of USB connection?

Tags: usb

[image]
I have 2.5" external hardrives that have this USB cable.

What is the this type of connection called?

Goggle return a number of results including:

Micro USB 3
Mini USB 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a male [USB 3 Micro-B](https://blog.macsales.com/14399-usb-3-0-brings-a-newish-plug) connection.  The larger part is the same as a USB 2 Micro-B connection and handles data transfer, where the smaller part provides power to the device.

It is definitely not a mini USB connection as that is different and the link shows the difference.

Comment: its quite confusing, but this helps a lot. Trying to make an unused external into an internal so looking for an appropriate adapted - which I don't think exists ...

Comment: If you take the harddrive out of its enclosure you will find it will possibly be able to be used internally inside your computer. If you intend to put it in a desktop and the drive is 2.5" then you may need adapters which are readily available. If you are intending it for a laptop or notebook you will need it to be 2.5" and match the connection type (SATA/IDE).

Comment: with these new drives the usb connectors are soldered onto the PCB, they don't come with traditional sata connectors.

Comment: @AasimAzam - That is interesting.

Comment: @AasimAzam, are you saying that your external HDD does not have the standard SATA connector between internal drive and USB 3.0 to SATA bridge?

Comment: The PCB has a female USB 3 Micro-B Connection rather than the standard sata connector. I think its to do with making the hard drive enclosure more compact.